# Deinit before UITapGestureRecognizer function is called

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a custom dialog for an app in which i would want to use closures that are called when the user taps on something, kinda like this:

```
var modal = ModalDialog(title: "modal title", buttonClick: { () -> Void in
            println("clicked")
        })

modal.show()
```

So I made a class called ModalDialog in which I have an UITapGestureRecognizer like so:

```
var modalTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("buttonClickAction:"))
modalView.addGestureRecognizer(modalTap)
```

My problem is that due to the ARC, when the tap is actually recognized and it tries to call `buttonClickAction:` the class is already deinitialised and the app crashes.

How would i go about keeping the ARC from deinitialising the modal until i explicitly tells it do to so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a strong reference of your modal dialog in view controller.

```
    var dialog : ModalDialog

    func show {
        // Keep strong reference dialog by property of your view controller
        self.dialog = ModalDialog(title: "modal title", buttonClick: { () -> Void in
            println("clicked")
        })
        self.dialog.show()
    }
```

Comment: This is what I have no idea how I would do, have looked in the Apple book and it doesn't make sense to me. ModalDialog is inited inside a view controller class, but how do I keep a strong reference to it?